# Is Conqueror's Haki Indiscriminate?

Tags: one-piece

***[Haoshoku Haki/Conquerors Haki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Haoshoku_Haki)*** by definition is:

> is a rare form of Haki that cannot be attained through training. Only one in several million people have this ability. This type of Haki allows the user to exert their willpower over others. It is said that whoever possesses this type of Haki has the qualities of a king.

As most have seen watching One Piece this form of Haki has a few displays from small scale to large. What I am asking is if it is indiscriminate. When released on a large scale can it spare individuals? I have seen the cases where single individuals can be targeted by this haki. (i.e. Shanks vs Seaking, Rayleigh vs Elephant) I know that it has been shown people withstanding the haki but that seems to be due more to fortitude of the individual than the user sparing those people. So could a conquerors haki user spare his/her crew if they know they are weak willed?

Comment: It isnt indiscriminate. Rayleigh touched on this subject when training Luffy. He said that luffy shouldnt use it until he could handle it properly to prevent unwanted "casualties". So it is indiscriminate when untrained like when luffy knocked out both allies and foes during the war.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, it isn't indiscriminate.**

It can be used by the user selectively.

As stated in the [Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki/Haoshoku_Haki):

> This type of Haki grants the user the ability to dominate the wills of others. The most common usage of it shown in the series so far is using it exert the user's willpower onto those with weak wills and rendering them unconscious. **Whilst inexperienced users are restricted to merely overpowering the will of one individual or blindly knocking out weak-willed people around them,** **those with more expertise can pick out weak-willed individuals in a large group and knock them out without affecting the others.**

An instance of this is shown when Camie isn't knocked out when [Rayleigh uses it for the first time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM1UCHQFpok).

Comment: oh guess i should have read the wiki better and not skimmed through it lol.